# How to establish connection between two machines using sockets

Tags: c, linux, sockets

I want to establish connection between two virtual machines using sockets programmed in C. Client socket is on Kali linux virtual machine and server socket is on Windows Server 2008 R2 VM. Network adapters on virtual machines are set to NAT. Server's IP address is 192.168.1.5 and client's IP address is 192.168.1.3 and there is connection, I have ping between them. Sockets work fine when both the client and server are on linux machine. But when I create and start server socket on server machine, I don't have connection between them and I can't get the message from server on the client socket. Can anyone help, please?? There is my code for sockets:

Server socket:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <sys/types.h>
#include <sys/socket.h>
#include <netinet/in.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <stdlib.h>


int main() {

    char server_message[256] = "YOU HAVE REACHED THE SERVER";
    int server_socket;
    server_socket = socket(AF_INET, SOCK_STREAM, 0);

    //DEFINE THE SERVER ADDRESS

    struct sockaddr_in server_address;
    server_address.sin_family = AF_INET;
    server_address.sin_port = htons(9002);
    server_address.sin_addr.s_addr = inet_addr("192.168.1.3");

    //BIND SOCKET TO OUR SPECIFIED IP AND PORT

    bind(server_socket, (struct sockaddr*)&server_address, sizeof(server_address));
    listen(server_socket, 5);
    int client_socket;

    client_socket = accept(server_socket, NULL, NULL);

    //SEND THE MESSAGE
    send(client_socket, server_message,sizeof(server_message),0);

    //close the socket

    close(server_socket);

    return 0; 
}
```

Client socket:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <sys/types.h>
#include <netinet/in.h>
#include <sys/socket.h>

int main() {

    int network_socket;

    network_socket = socket(AF_INET, SOCK_STREAM, 0);

    //specify an address for the socket

    struct sockaddr_in server_address;
    server_address.sin_family = AF_INET;
    server_address.sin_port = htons(9002);
    server_address.sin_addr.s_addr = inet_addr("192.168.1.5");

    int connection_status = connect(network_socket, (struct sockaddr *) &server_address, sizeof(server_address));
    char server_response[256];
    recv(network_socket, &server_response, sizeof(server_response), 0);
    printf("THE SERVER SENT THE DATA: %s \n", server_response);

    close(network_socket);
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: have you try with other program like netcat ?

Comment: If the server's IP is `192.168.1.5` why are you trying to bind on `1.3` here `server_address.sin_addr.s_addr = inet_addr("192.168.1.3");` ?

Comment: You need to be checking return values. You are attempting to bind the client's address (192.168.1.3) on the server machine (192.168.1.5); that will never work. Almost certain the `bind` call is failing but you don't know because you're not checking the return values. Probably you should be using the wildcard address (`INADDR_ANY`) for the bind anyway.

Comment: Thanks a lot, Ajay Brahmakshatriya, after I put 1.5, it worked!

Comment: Tip: One normally binds to `INADDR_ANY` (`inet_addr("0.0.0.0")`) (to accept connections from anywhere) or `INADDR_LOOPBACK` (`inet_addr("127.0.0.1")`) (to only accept connection to `localhost` from the local machine). It's weird/unusual to bind to another other addresses.